# limit the number of stack trace lines when exception is generated in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way i can control the number of stack trace lines generated when a exception scenario happen in a rails application.

The reason for this is i need the stack trace but not all the lines and other reason my log file grows to a huge amount after a while.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy setting to adjust rails logging output, however you can create your own logger with ActiveSuppport.

Check out these links to get started.

http://rubyjunky.com/cleaning-up-rails-4-production-logging.html
https://github.com/gshaw/concise_logging